# How to iterate through a column in data frame in python and get the arithmetic calculation corresponding to the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, multiple-columns

Data Frame:(small data frame provided)
(actual data frame is large)

| Item Type | Item Weight | grp cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Baking Goods | 4.880 | 5 |
| Baking Goods | 4.920 | 5 |
| Baking Goods | 5.260 | 5 |
| Baking Goods | 5.425 | 3 |
| Breads | 5.035 | 4 |
| Breads | 5.260 | 2 |
| Breakfast | 7.895 | 9 |
| Breakfast | 8.060 | 7 |

using above data frame calculations to be done:

1. Baking Goods = [(4.880 * 5) + (4.920 * 5) + (5.260 * 5) + (5.425 * 3)]

   = (24.4  +  24.6  + 26.3  + 16.275)/(18)
2. Breads   =[(5.035 * 2)+(5.260 * 2)]/4

[same calculation as 1) according to data frame]

3. Breakfast = [(7.895 * 9)+(8.060 * 7)]/16

[same calculation as 1) according to data frame]

Comment: Is `mean` correct? Because `(4.880 * 5) + (4.920 * 5) + (5.260 * 5) + (5.425 * 3)` return scalar `91.57499999999999`, so mean not exist. If use `[(4.880 * 5) + (4.920 * 5) + (5.260 * 5) + (5.425 * 3)]` get `[91.57499999999999]` - then mean only remove `[]`.

Comment: why only `baking goods ` is getting multiplied by `grp cnt`?

Comment: modified the question.

Comment: Can you check the answer and see if it helps?

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need multiple values and then aggregate sum like:

```
df = df.assign(new = df['Item Weight'].mul(df['grp cnt'])).groupby('Item Type')['new'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `groupby` and then `apply`.

```
df = df.groupby('Item Type').apply(lambda x: x.prod(axis=1).sum()/x['grp cnt'].sum())
```

OR

```
x = df.set_index('Item Type')
df = x.prod(axis=1).groupby('Item Type').sum().div(x.groupby('Item Type')['grp cnt'].sum())
```

---

**df:**

```
Item Type
Baking Goods    5.087500
Breads          5.110000
Breakfast       7.967187
dtype: float64
```